# Send gps data on server in background mode in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps

I would like to create an app for iphone that collect the geolocation data and send it to a server. This app should do all this stuff during it is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new API provided in ios 7 called iOS Background Fetch
Below are the links those provide tuts for the same

[Link 1](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch/)
 [Link 2](http://hayageek.com/ios-background-fetch/)
 [Link 3](http://www.devfright.com/ios-7-background-app-refresh-tutorial/)

Comment: i used ios 6, whats can i do for ios6